# How Can we test The presence of Image Zoom in a E-commerce website

Tags: testing, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

If you visit Flipkart, an Indian e-commerce website, you'll find the zoom-image capability in any listed item. This functionality opens up zoomed image of the article, as soon as the mouse is hovered over it.

My question is- can we determine, that the image is actually zoomed up in the webpage.

I mean, if a user hovers a mouse over the image of article, the zoom has actually opened up and is showing the zoomed image of the article.

Can we automate this kind of scenario using Selenium Webdriver.[image: Flipkart Image Zooming Functionality]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you hover over `.productImage.current`, then `.productImageZoom` is set from `display:none` to `display: block`.  Something like this should work:

```
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
WebElement elem = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".productImage.current"));
action.moveToElement(elem);
action.perform();
this.sleep(2);  // This may not be necessary

if (driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".productImageZoom")).isVisible())
{
    // success!
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working code:

```
public class TestingECommerce {

    public static void main(String args[]){

        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        //Navigate to a shoe's page in flipkart
        driver.get("http://www.flipkart.com/fila-scroll-sneakers/p/itmey3f8ssgrdgdh?pid=SHOEY3F8HUHFVYJ9&srno=b_1&ref=2918f415-8924-46e9-8b99-993850a8cb48");

        //Hovering over image
        Actions act = new Actions(driver);
        act.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='imgWrapper']/img[1]"))).build().perform();

        //Waiting 10 seconds for the zoomed element to be visible
        WebElement ele_zoom = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='productImageZoom']"));
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(ele_zoom));

        if(ele_zoom.isDisplayed())
            System.out.println("The zoom is visible");  
        else
            System.err.println("The zoom isn't visible!!");
    }
   }
```

**The above code navigates to a shoe's page in Flipkart site. Then it hovers over the image, that results into the visibility of zoomed view for the image. It waits 10 seconds till the visibility of the zoomed view for the element is detected, and then it asserts if the zoomed view for the element is getting displayed or not.**

Answer (score 0):

in addition to above answer, you can certainly check some more property of desired element by getting driver.getAttribute("src") or something like that..